# pass mysqli to child thread for execution and back

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CLI script that executes mysql queries simultaneously by forking child threads.

I create 4 mysqli objects in the parent and assign each to the child. Here is what I need to do:

- As a child, use the parent's `mysqli` object to execute `$mysqli->autocommit(0)`.
- As a child, execute an `INSERT` statement.
- As a parent, execute `$mysqli->commit()` for each of the 4 connections.

Is it possible to keep the same connection open between parent and children to implement commits?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for _persistent_ connections?

Comment: i'm looking to be able to use the same connection between a parent thread and a child thread.. i'm not sure if persistent connections would help me..

Comment: Threads in PHP; how are you implementing it? `php_pthreads` extension? is concurrency(context switching) implemented?

Comment: Seems like the fork() should work but I'd wonder what will happen to the connection object when the child closes. Also - what is the parent doing while the child is executing? (sounds like family therapy...) I'd worry about conflicts (again.. strange metaphor..)